# find all rational numbers $a,b$ such that $3$ divides $a+b+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

find all rational numbers $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $3\, | \, \left(a+b+\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}\right)$

I solved it in integer numbers but I couldn't solve in in rational numbers because I can't use to be divisible something with some thing else.

I also supposed $a=\dfrac{m}{n}$ such that $gcd(m,n)=1$ and $b=\dfrac{p}{q}$ such that $gcd(p,q)=1$ but I was not able to continue to a solution.

Comment: sorry now it is true . they are rational numbers

Comment: Continuing the nitpicking to clarify. You probably want $a+b+1/a+1/b$ to be an **integer** multiple of $3$. When you switch from one ring to another the meaning of "divides" also changes. But, because the rational numbers form a field every non-zero rational number "divides" every other. So in the ring of rational numbers $4$ is divisible by $3$ because $4=3\cdot\dfrac43$. I do suspect that you want $a+b+1/a+1/b$ to be equal to one of $\pm3$, $\pm6$ et cetera.

Comment: Your first expression factors as $\dfrac{(ab+1)(a+b)}{ab}$. When written in terms of integers $m,n,p,q$ this becomes $\dfrac{(mp+nq)(mq+np)}{mp}$. Perhaps that can help?

Comment: @John Wayland Bales I solved it but I don't know how to use match Jax and write the answer.can you help me?

Comment: If you write it neatly by hand and take a clear cell phone photo you can post that as your answer. If it is not too long perhaps I could take the time to re-write it in MathJax. But this is a good opportunity to learn a bit of MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference You can write your answer a bit at a time. You will see the results immediately below the edit window and make corrections. And you can also post partial results and edit to add more.

Comment: Basic mathjax is just dollar signs surrounding your formula. You can use detoxify website to look up particular symbols by drawing them. BTW interested to see solution

Comment: @John Wayland Bales thanks a lot I will try it

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales I post the answer with photo's links, please edit the answer

Comment: @Χpẘ I post the answer with photoes links can you edit it and write the solution.please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I am not good at using math Jax I wrote a neat solution and I took photos if some body is able to use math Jax please edit the answer and write the solution the first link is a solution and the next is proof of a theorem that I used it in my solution

http://s8.picofile.com/file/8302280634/20170801_170848_1.jpg

http://s8.picofile.com/file/8302280926/20170801_170859_1.jpg